# Live data update with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, api

I have an API which works well, however I would like it to be live (get data periodically from API and show it in my html code).

I just need some hint that from where I most start. Javascript, Ajax?

Any clue would be appreciated.

My PHP / HTML:

```
<h4>Cpu Load</h4>
<span class="text-muted"><?php 
    echo "" . $first['cpu-load'] . " %" . ""; 
?></span>
```

Which outputs 2% or whatever. On refresh the page updates the new value.

My PHP API:

```
<?php
 require('includes/routeros_api.class.php');
  $API = new RouterosAPI();
   $API->debug = false;
    if ($API->connect('MYIP', 'USER', 'PASS')) { 
      $ARRAY = $API->comm("/system/resource/print");
        $first = $ARRAY['0'];
  $API->disconnect();
 }
?>
```

Comment: you could use a javascript timer with setInterval function to run every x seconds. make sure you implement the ajax call within it.

Comment: It's good to return json in your API. And for making it live, you can get the data periodically from you API with `Ajax` update your DOM with it.
Also a bad approach is refreshing you page with headers: `header("Refresh: 2")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setInterval function to query the API every certain time:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

The convenient way for me is using Vue and Vue-resource via data-binding, after querying API and change data, the page will be re-rendered without refresh the whole page.

Comment: Easy as <script type="text/javascript">
 var timeout = setInterval(reload, 1000);    
function reload () {

     $('#uptime').load('includes/functions/uptime.php');
}
 </script>

Comment: @user2720970 yes, that's the simplest solution

Answer (score 1):

To keep things simple you could create a function that has your ajax call.
You should look up the .ajax jquery usage, but this gives you an idea.

```
function ajaxQuery(){
    // some stuff inside here to perform call
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your-file.php',
        dataType: 'what ever data type you expect from server...',
        success: function(data) {
            // this is where i would normal have an id setup to update 
            // a specific textbox or form field...
        }

   });


}
```

You will then have to use the javascript timer function setInterval() somewhere on your page:

```
setInterval(ajaxQuery(), 2000);
```